# Geometric interpretation of a closed sub variety

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Any linear subspace $A\subset\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$, where $A=\bigcap^m_{i=1} Z(f_i)$ with $f_i\in\mathbb{C}[x_0,...,x_n]$ being some linear forms, is a closed sub variety and there exists uniquely a $b$ where $b=dim(A)$, such that $A\simeq\mathbb{P}^b(\mathbb{C})$.

Any advice/guidance on how to prove this would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : this is a closed variety by definition. Let's show it's linear. Look in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. Your $f_i$ lift to linear form $\tilde f_i \in (\mathbb C^{n+1})^{\vee}$, i.e hyperplane of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. Now it is clear that the intersection of these hyperplane is a linear subspace $\tilde A \subset \mathbb C^{n+1}$ of dimension $a+1$. I claim that $\pi(\tilde A) = A$, and so $b = a$.

Comment: thank you for the hint. However what exactly is $\pi$ here? Is it the mapping from $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Yes exactly. ${}$